# How to repeat a lookahead pattern?

Tags: regex

If I have a lookahead for example: `(?<===)(.*?)(?=&)`, which is to match something between == and &. How do I repeat this lookahead to match multiple something (such as string) between == and & in a long string?

Comment: Use the `g` flag for multiple matches.

Comment: You just need a g flag and your regex is fine

Comment: just add a global and dotall modifier http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/18